# Can't get actual filesize

Tags: php, filesize

I'm working on a class whose purpose is to restrict users to making only 10 requests within any 30 second period. It utilizes a file to maintain IP addresses, last request time. and the number of tries they've made. The problem is that, no matter what I try, I can't get the filesize. I've tried using `clearstatcache()`, and I've tried using a function I found in the comments on the filesize() page of the PHP manual.

Here's the code, in it's current debugging state.

```
// Makes sure user can only try to generate a coupon x number of times over x amount of seconds
class IpChecker{    
    const WAIT_TIME = 30; //seconds until user can try again
    const MAX_TRIES = 10; // maximum tries

    const COUPON_IP = 0;
    const COUPON_TIME = 1;
    const COUPON_TRIES = 2;

    private $ip_data;
    private $path;
    private $fh;
    private $safe;

    public function __construct(){
        clearstatcache();

        $this->path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/ips/.ips";
        $this->fh = fopen($this->path,'w+');
        $this->filesize = $this->realfilesize($this->fh);
        echo "fs: ".$this->filesize; exit;


        $this->getIPs();
        $this->checkIP();
        $this->logRequest();
        fclose($this->fh);
        $this->safe || die(json_encode("You have exhausted all available tries. Please try again later."));
    }

    private function logRequest(){
        $str = "";
        foreach($this->ip_data as $data){
            foreach($data as $col){
                if(self::WAIT_TIME < (time() - $col[self::COUPON_TIME])) $str .= $col."\t";
            }
            $str = rtrim($str, '\t');
            $str .= "\n";
        }
        $str = rtrim($str, '\n');
        try{
            $fw = fwrite($this->fh, $str) || die(json_encode("Unable to check IP"));
        }catch(Exception $e){
            die(json_encode($e));
        }
    }

    private function checkIP(){     
        $IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $TIME = time();
        $safe = true;
        $user_logged = false;
        echo "<pre>"; var_dump($this->ip_data); exit;
        foreach($this->ip_data as $key=>$data){
            echo "<prE>"; var_dump($data); exit;
//          if($data[$key][self::COUPON_IP] == $IP){
//              $user_logged = true;
//              if(
//                  (($TIME - $data[$key][self::COUPON_TIME]) < self::WAIT_TIME) ||
//                  (self::MAX_TRIES >= $data[$key][self::COUPON_TRIES])
//              ) $safe = false;
//              $this->ip_data[$key][self::COUPON_TRIES] = $this->ip_data[$key][self::COUPON_TRIES]+1;
//              $this->ip_data[$key][self::COUPON_TIME] = $TIME;
//          }
        }
        if(!$user_logged){
            die("user not logged");
            $this->ip_data[] = array(
                self::COUPON_IP => $IP,
                self::COUPON_TIME => $TIME,
                self::COUPON_TRIES => 1
            );
        }
        $this->safe = $safe;
    }

    private function getIPs(){
        $IP_DATA = array();
        echo file_get_contents($this->path); exit;
        // this always returns 0. 
        $size = filesize($this->path);
        echo "filesize: ".$size; exit;
        if($size){
            $IPs = fread($this->fh,$size);
            $IP_ARR = explode("\n",$IPs);
            foreach($IP_ARR as $line) $IP_DATA[] = explode("\t",$line);
        }
        $this->ip_data = $IP_DATA;
    }

    // Copied from the comments in the PHP Manual for filesize()
    public function realfilesize($fp) {
        $return = false;
        if (is_resource($fp)) {
            if (PHP_INT_SIZE < 8) {
                // 32bit
                if (0 === fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_END)) {
                    $return = 0.0;
                    $step = 0x7FFFFFFF;
                    while ($step > 0) {
                        if (0 === fseek($fp, - $step, SEEK_CUR)) {
                            $return += floatval($step);
                        } else {
                            $step >>= 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } elseif (0 === fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_END)) {
                // 64bit
                $return = ftell($fp);
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }
}
```

***How can I get the real filesize? I'm on PHP 5.2.***

Comment: stat caches are per-process. each hit on your script is a separate process, so there'd be no point in clearing the stat cache, unless you do stat-based operations multiple times within the SAME script process.

Comment: @MarcB, I realize that, but afaik, it won't hurt anythign either and I'm getting desperate so I thought I'd give it a shot.

Comment: and note that IPs have never been a valid way to identify a single user. e.g. consider that pretty much every single cell phone is behing a NAT gateway. That means you're treating huge swaths of users as a single person and limiting them as a group, not as individuals.

Comment: Off topic, but I **strongly** suggest you upgrade your PHP version as soon as possible. PHP 5.2 has been obsolete for years. Even 5.3 is end-of-life now; the oldest version that is still actually supported is 5.4, and even that will end support fairly soon. By sticking with such an old version, you are virtually guaranteeing that your site has major security holes.

Comment: @Simba Unfortunately I don't have that level of control. Wish I could. :(

Comment: @MarcB, I know, but these users are not authenticated and the majority of them should not need anywhere near the maximum allotted 10 tries. This is my best option.

Comment: What does it mean, you can't get file size using `filesize()`? What does it return instead of expected size? Does it throw any error?

Comment: @RomanHocke, `filesize()` returns 0 no matter what. `file_get_contents()` returns empty string. `file_exists()` returns true. `is_readable()` and `is_writable()` both return true. The file itself is temporarily chmodded to 777 and is not empty.

Comment: Strange. Does it throw some error, when You use `error_reporting(E_ALL)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn;t able to figure out what was wrong with my code, if anythign, but I worked around it like this:

```
/**
 * Makes sure user can only access a given page
 * x number of times over x amount of seconds.
 * If multiple instances of this class are used, the $namespace
 * properties for each should be unique.
 * Default wait time is 90 seconds while default request limit
 * is 10 tries.
 * 
 * -+ Usage +-
 * Just create the object with any parameters, no need to assign,
 * just make sure it's initialized at the top of the page:
 * new RequestThrottler;
 * 
 * -+- Parameters -+-
 * null RequestThrottler ( [ string $namespace [, int $WaitTime [, int $MaxTries ] ] ] )
 */
class RequestThrottler{
    // settings
    private static $WAIT_TIME; // seconds until count expires
    private static $MAX_TRIES; // maximum tries

    // used to keep session variables unique
    // in the event that this class is used in multiple places.
    private $namespace;

    // for debugging
    const DBG = false;

    // array index constants
    const _TIME = 0;
    const _TRIES = 1;

    // defines whether or not access is permitted
    private $safe;

    // seconds until reset
    private $secs; 

    /**
     * -+- Constructor -+-
     * @param String $namespace - A unique prefix for SESSION data
     * @param Int $WaitTime - Total seconds before user can try again
     * @param Int $MaxTries - Total tries user can make until their request is denied
     */
    public function __construct($namespace='Throttler', $WaitTime=90, $MaxTries=10){
        // make sure a session is available
        if(!headers_sent() && !isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
        if(!isset($_SESSION)) die(json_encode("No session available"));

        // save settings
        $this->namespace = $namespace;
        self::$MAX_TRIES = $MaxTries;
        self::$WAIT_TIME = $WaitTime;

        // do the footwork
        $this->checkHistory();

        // if set to debug mode, print a short helpful string
        if(self::DBG) die(json_encode(
                "You are ".($this->safe ? 'SAFE' : 'NOT SAFE')."! "
                . "This is try number {$_SESSION[$this->namespace.'_ATTEMPTS'][self::_TRIES]} of ".self::$MAX_TRIES.". "
                . $this->secs." seconds since last attempt. "
                . (self::$WAIT_TIME - $this->secs)." seconds until reset."
            ));

        // if not safe, kill the script, show a message
        $this->safe || die(json_encode("You're going too fast. Please try again in ".(self::$WAIT_TIME - $this->secs)." seconds."));
    }

    /**
     * -+- checkHistory -+-
     * Does the footwork to determine whether
     * or not to throttle the current user/request.
     */
    private function checkHistory(){
        $TIME = time();
        $safe = true;

        // make sure session is iniitialized
        if( !isset($_SESSION[$this->namespace.'_ATTEMPTS']) || 
            !isset($_SESSION[$this->namespace.'_ATTEMPTS'][self::_TRIES]) || 
            !isset($_SESSION[$this->namespace.'_ATTEMPTS'][self::_TIME])   ) 
                $_SESSION[$this->namespace.'_ATTEMPTS'] = array(
                    self::_TIME =>$TIME,
                    self::_TRIES => 1
                );
        else $_SESSION[$this->namespace.'_ATTEMPTS'][self::_TRIES] = 
                $_SESSION[$this->namespace.'_ATTEMPTS'][self::_TRIES]+1;

        // get seconds since last attempt
        $secondSinceLastAttempt = $TIME - $_SESSION[$this->namespace.'_ATTEMPTS'][self::_TIME];

        // reset the counter if the wait time has expired
        if($secondSinceLastAttempt  > self::$WAIT_TIME){
            $_SESSION[$this->namespace.'_ATTEMPTS'][self::_TIME] = $TIME;
            $_SESSION[$this->namespace.'_ATTEMPTS'][self::_TRIES] = 1;
            $secondSinceLastAttempt  = 0;
        }

        // finally, determine if we're safe
        if($_SESSION[$this->namespace.'_ATTEMPTS'][self::_TRIES] >= self::$MAX_TRIES) $safe=false;

        // log this for debugging
        $this->secs = $secondSinceLastAttempt;

        // save the "safe" flag
        $this->safe = $safe;
    }
}
```